# Language switch between two language in SharePoint Online Communication site

Tags: sharepoint-online, multilingual, spfx, spfx-extension

Hello everyone I need your kind support after lot of search work I come to know there is no straight forward method in SharePoint Online to change language, I want a dropdown that will change between 'English' and 'Arabic'. is there any customization required? like using **SharePoint Framework** or change of setting in SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

You can use google translate for language translation.Below link provide the example of google translation :

Link of google translate demo for spfx solution : https://ravichandran.blog/2020/06/17/google-translate-in-spfx/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).